# How to assign many blockers at the same time?

Tags: magic-the-gathering-arena

These days with [Field of the Dead](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=467001) it is not unusual to block 40 zombies with 40 zombies. I've sometimes seen my opponents being able to do that very quickly, so I feel like there is some interface trick I am missing. Any ideas?

Comment: Even such a limited set of cards as MTGA already has Infinite Token setups. Shows how many of these there is. For instance, a friend of mine has a Goat deck. Another crammed out his old-ish Withering deck and added Hapatra and Scarab Nest, and literally painted himself some dice saying Infinity. Personally, I once theory crafted a combo with Oath of Teferi and Oath of Gideon to create infinite Jace tokens... I think with a few more cards the meta would be a bit more versatile.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can quick-assign blockers by simply clicking both stack indicators when assigning blockers. Note however, that it only works if you have **stacks of tokens**.

> - When attacking or blocking with a stack of tokens, you can click on
>     the stack indicator (“x4”) to issue attack or block commands to the
>     entire stack.
>
>   - When declaring a stack of tokens as blockers against a stack of attackers, clicking on the top creature in the attacking stack
>       declares all of the blockers on that creature, and clicking on the
>       stack indicator of the attacking stack will declare the blockers 1:1
>       with the attackers.

[Source](https://mtgarena.pro/news/mtga-february-patch-0-12-00-00/)